# Novo chat para tradução!

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, tradução, chat

Nosso [projeto no Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/) vai muito bem. Nós somos, de longe, o site com tradução mais avançada. A dedicação de todo mundo que participou é impressionante e todo mundo que participa do SOpt deve muito ao trabalho dos tradutores e tradutoras do projeto.

Ainda assim, o trabalho de tradução nunca está *realmente* terminado. Strings novas estão sempre sendo adicionadas ao SOpt (os devs trabalham... mesmo que não pareça, algumas vezes), algumas coisas são mudadas aqui e ali. Além de coisas que já estão traduzidas, mas podem ser melhoradas.

Pra ajudar todo mundo que quer participar, seja traduzindo ou discutindo traduções e problemas, temos uma nova sala de chat:

#### http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27048/traducao-do-sopt

Lá todo mundo pode apontar problemas, discutir traduções, mandar screenshots, o que for preciso pra garantir que o SOpt continue sempre bem traduzido.

Além disso, um bot vai avisar sempre que novas strings forem adicionadas ao projeto, pra que todo mundo possa saber quando tem coisa nova precisando de uma tradução.

Além disso, nós estamos pensando em maneiras de recompensar quem vem ajudando na tradução. Não temos nada concreto ainda, mas algumas boas ideias já apareceram.

Continuem ajudando e participando. O SOpt é melhor graças a vocês!

Comment: Ótima ideia. Acho que criar perguntas para discutir detalhes de tradução ou para discutir coisas muito polêmicas (que tem muitas réplicas) é muito inviável.

Comment: Medalhas seriam ótimas recompensas, creio eu.