# Como ajudar quem traduz o site?

Tags: debate, tradução

> ## tl; dr
>
> A tradução é o "patinho feio" de todas as coisas que a comunidade pode fazer para ajudar o site a melhorar. Sabemos do problema mas precisamos da ajuda de vocês para saber como melhorar.

## Antes de tudo, parabéns!

O trabalho de tradução do SOpt até agora tem sido espetacular. Estamos usando a ajuda de vocês nas traduções do site [há menos de um ano](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2705), e nesse período o site saiu de "*grande parte traduzido, mais ou menos*" para "*quase totalmente traduzido, bem traduzido*". O mérito inteiro desse sucesso é dos nossos intrépidos tradutores. As intrépidas pessoas que assumiram a responsibilidade de desbravar o Transifex, buscar as partes que precisavam ser consertadas e gastaram centenas de horas ajudando o Stack Overflow em Português a ficar muito melhor.

Nosso projeto hoje tem 7582 strings, sendo 92% delas traduzidas. Já estivemos bem mais próximos de 100% traduzidos, mas com a recente adição de funcionalidades, como [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/9835) e [Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312452), o número de strings deu um salto muito grande, e ainda estamos correndo atrás do prejuízo.

Nossos tradutores estão de parabéns e todos no site devem bastante a eles.

[image: O Homemmorcego agradece a todos os heróis nossos de cada dia]

## Mas nem tudo são flores

É importante ressaltar que nossos tradutores fizeram esse excelente trabalho mesmo tendo que lidar com ferramentas e processos absolutamente deficientes:

- As strings não tem o contexto necessário
- Algumas delas estão em áreas restritas do site
- É difícil saber quando, e onde, tem algo que precisa ser traduzido
- Mudanças no site significam que algumas traduções são perdidas sem que ninguém saiba
- Traduções afunilam na fila de revisão
- Não é possível ver o resultado imediatamente
- Algumas coisas que não precisariam ser traduzidas vão parar no Transifex de qualquer maneira

Enfim... É bem claro que qualquer um que deseje se dedicar a traduzir o site vai enfrentar uma montanha de problemas, que não condiz com a maneira como costumamos tratar nossas comunidades. O lema do Stack Overflow sempre foi "vocês nos ajudam, nós ajudamos vocês".

É hora de fazer isso valer também para as bravas, e bilingues, almas do SOpt.

Então precisamos da ajuda de vocês...

### Se você já ajuda a traduzir o site:

Gostaríamos de saber, entre outras coisas que você puder dizer:

- **Qual seu processo de tradução?**
  Você usa o site normalmente e vai ao Transifex quando vê algo que precisa de ajustes? Você acessa a lista de coisas não traduzidas no Transifex e começa a traduzir tudo por lá? Enfim... como é o seu dia a dia traduzindo o SOpt?
- **Quais as maiores, ou mais comuns, pedras no seu caminho?**
  Você precisa de mais contexto? Você nunca sabe por onde começar? Dá trabalho ir até o Transifex buscar a string correta para traduzir? Quais são as coisas que te fazem respirar fundo e te dão vontade de largar tudo?
- **O que te motiva a traduzir? O que pode ser feito para te motivar mais?**
  A tradução talvez seja o trabalho mais "ingrato" da comunidade. Não dá reputação, não dá privilégios, não dá chapéus... Mas alguma coisa te motiva a seguir em frente. O que?
- **Que ferramentas você sente falta?**
  O Meta podia ter mais posts sobre tradução? As ferramentas de gerência do projeto no Transifex estão sendo sub-utilizadas? Nossa [sala de chat](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4240/) (e o bot) tem pouca utilidade? Você gostaria de receber notificações sobre novas strings a serem traduzidas?
- **O que pode ser feito para te ajudar?**
  Sua lista de problemas é tremendamente útil pra gente, mas se você tiver alguma sugestão de solução nós ficamos ainda mais gratos. Você tem uma noção muito melhor de como é a rotina de tradução, e é capaz de sugerir coisas muito melhores do que um bando de programadores (que nem falam Português, exceto a [Roberta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/901/rla4)!) seriam capazes de sugerir.
- **Algum outro problema?**
  Recentemente a [carla reparou](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4708/stack-overflow-jobs-para-o-brasil#comment15361_4711) que as strings do SO Jobs estavam disponíveis no Transifex, mesmo sem planos no momento de habilitar a ferramenta no SOpt. Isso foi uma falha *grave* da nossa parte e não queremos que problemas assim aconteçam de novo, em respeito ao trabalho de vocês. Você vê algum outro problema parecido no nosso processo de tradução? O que te aflige?

### Se você não traduz o SOpt, ou parou de traduzir

- **Por quê?**
  Claro que tem gente que não fala inglês, e que nem todo mundo tem vontade de traduzir (e nem é obrigado). Mas se você já teve vontade, ou até chegou a traduzir um pouco, mas acabou desistindo, quais foram os motivos? Faltam incentivos? É tudo muito complicado? Você nem sabia que isso existia? A vida é curta demais para gastar tempo no Transifex?
- **Alguma sugestão sobre como te motivar?**
  Pergunta parecida, mas um pouco diferente... Se algum momento da vida você já desejou que o site tivesse algo a mais para te convencer a traduzir, estamos aqui para te ouvir!
- **Você sabe o que fazer caso encontre algo que precisa ser traduzido?**
  Se no seu dia a dia você se depara com coisas que estão erradas, ou em inglês, você vem avisar no Meta? Você gostaria que houvesse uma maneira mais prática de resolver esses problemas? Você gostaria de saber exatamente com quem falar sobre esses problemas?

## Por um Stack Overflow em Português *em português!*

Nosso site depende da tradução comunitária para continuar saudável e crescendo. Ninguém levaria a sério um site com "em Português" no nome, mas que não está *em português*! Nós ajudamos vocês a manterem a qualidade do site em todas as outras áreas, e é hora de reconhecer quem se dedicou a mais essa.

Não podemos garantir que as coisas vão mudar imediatamente, e nem que todas as soluções vão sempre ser excepcionais e maravilhas. Mas com a ajuda de vocês nós podemos ter muito mais certeza de que cada passo, por menor que seja, vai ser dado na direção correta.

Comment: Devo responder estas perguntas novamente aqui?

Comment: @carla não seria nada mal, já que suas respostas podem ajudar outras pessoas a pensar no assunto :)

Comment: Até ajudaria, mas não tenho domínio em inglês para tal e é péssimo usar ferramentas de traduçoes, que as vezes mais atrapalham o entendimento do que ajudam.

Comment: @carla Onde você já respondeu antes?

Comment: @bfavaretto A carla é a tradutora mais ativa, em todos os nosso projetos, então quando começamos a pensar nisso eu entrei em contato com ela, explicando o que a gente tem em mente e pedindo sugestões. O que ela já respondeu ajudou bastante a definir algumas coisas, mas esse questionário é um pouco mais amplo, então quanto mais gente participar, melhor

Comment: A discussão é antiga @Gabe, mas foi decidido alguma coisa? Medalhas extras, pontuação, um íconezinho para diferenciar? Algo a nos dizer?

Comment: @Stormwind Infelizmente, não... A mesma falta de recurso para resolver o problema afeta também essas partes tangenciais. Eu gostaria de ter uma notícia melhor, mas...

Answer (score 25):

> Qual seu processo de tradução?

- acessar o Transifex;
- ver as string que precisam de tradução;
- caso encontre uma palavra ou expressão de múltiplas traduções dou uma
  busca nas strings já traduzidas para buscar o termo usado;
- caso encontre algum erro ou algo que valha a pena discutir posto no chat
  do SOpt...mas bem, não recebo lá muitas respostas;
- caso alguma
  expressão dependa muito do contexto eu evito traduzir.

> Quais as maiores, ou mais comuns, pedras no seu caminho?

*Preguiça*: entretanto uma vez que venço a barreira de energia mínima pra começar eu me empolgo e traduzo vários blocos.

*Contexto*: há blocos cuja tradução depende muito do contexto, se desse para localizá-las no site seria ótimo.

> O que te motiva a traduzir? O que pode ser feito para te motivar mais?

É a minha maneira de agradecer a comunidade SO.

Uso frequentemente o SO no meu trabalho, mas raramente consigo contribuir. Acho que não tenho tanto conhecimento para perguntas complexas e as perguntas fáceis são respondidas antes que eu chegue...pelo menos é a minha impressão.

O que motivaria mais? Acho que se fosse possível atrelar a tradução ao sistema de pontuação mais pessoas ficariam interessadas.
De minha parte, eu acharia muito legal ganhar uma camiseta do SO. [não custa nada tentar...]

> Que ferramentas você sente falta?

Só sinto falta da possibilidade de encontrar o contexto do bloco a ser traduzido, as ferramentas do Transifex eu já acho muito boas.

Acho que o bot ou qualquer tipo de sinalização de novas strings só tem utilidade quando se traduziu tudo e eventualmente vão chegando novas coisas. Atualmente, em que ainda temos trocentas strings pra tradução, o bot ficar postando zilhões de linhas é meio inútil.

Acho que o chat é sub-utilizado. Já postei algumas vezes lá para discutir traduções, mas geralmente apenas um ou dois respondem.

**EDIT [18/01]**

Acho que o processo de 'aprovação' das traduções é ineficaz. Acredito que só os moderadores tem esse poder, e como eles tem outros afazeres, acabam não tendo muito tempo para isso.
Talvez valesse a pena permitir uma 'fila de aprovação', ou seja, se 2 [ou 3, ou n] outros tradutores revisassem a tradução de um outro e a aprovassem, ela ficaria como 'revisada'.

Comment: "De minha parte, eu acharia muito legal ganhar uma camiseta do SO. [não custa nada tentar...]" :D

Comment: "Acho que se fosse possível atrelar a tradução ao sistema de pontuação mais pessoas ficariam interessadas."
Realmente, funciona no Steam...

Comment: @EMBarbosa De fato,  se a Steam consegue fazer pessoas usarem aplicações para ficar farmando cartinhas e sites que mostram as badges mais baratas para vc conseguir subir mais de nível com menos gasto, acho que conseguimos fazer as galeras traduzirem uns textinhos.

Comment: Todas as sugestões são ótimas, e bem alinhadas com o que a gente vem pensando. O processo de revisão precisa de uma... revisão (haha!) e a gente vem trabalhando em algo que pode ajudar um pouco com o contexto. Depois disso, vamos ver o que fazer quanto ao reconhecimento, pelo menos visual, dos tradutores. Mais uma vez, obrigado!

Answer (score 17):

> Se você não traduz o SOpt, ou parou de traduzir
>   Por quê?

Sempre tive vontade de ajudar a traduzir o site, mas nunca encontrei uma opção dentro do mesmo que pudesse me ajudar a dar o primeiro passo. Pra falar a verdade, nem sei se existe tal opção.

> Alguma sugestão sobre como te motivar?

Seria interessante se o site convidasse o usuário para colaborar na tradução, através de uma notificação de tempos em tempo por exemplo, e que também tivesse uma opção, na página de perfil por exemplo, onde o usuário poderia optar por se tornar um tradutor, algo como "Junte-se ao time de tradutores do Stack Overflow em Português!".

Outra coisa também, eu não tenho a menor ideia de como as traduções das strings do site são feitas, mas pelo visto é feito em outra plataforma/site não é? Bom, seria ótimo se essas traduções pudessem ser feitas por dentro da plataforma Stack Exchange mesmo, e que essas traduções rendessem medalhas também.

Mais uma coisa, seria interessante distinguir os usuários que colaboram com a tradução, "usuários que fazem parte do time de tradução do Stack Overflow em Português", dos outros usuários, talvez com um ícone a mais naquela parte que mostra o autor das perguntas/respostas.

Assim por exemplo:

[image]

> Você sabe o que fazer caso encontre algo que precisa ser traduzido?

Não tenho a menor ideia, mas provavelmente iria abrir uma postagem no Meta do site pedindo auxílio de algum moderador.

Comment: Excelente a ideia da notificação no perfil, e as medalhas, e o símbolo. Traduzir dentro da nossa plataforma é **bem** complicado, mas talvez nós possamos fazer algo para anunciar melhor a existência do [nosso projeto no Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/dashboard/) e como fazer para participar dele. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Gabe, que tal um tutorial/faq aqui no Meta? Tipo passos básicos para quem nunca nem Transi nem Fex...

Comment: @brasofilo Boa ideia. Não posso prometer pra agora, mas é realmente uma boa ideia

Answer (score 10):

Vou direto ao ponto, respondendo às perguntas:

#### Qual seu processo de tradução?

Eu faço traduções em "blocos". Fui mais ativo quando o processo começou, e depois começaram a sobrar só umas coisas "não traduzíveis", então deixei de lado. Depois disso voltei uma ou duas vezes, e agora de novo por causa dessa novidade (pra mim) que "caímos" para 92%.

Objetivamente, eu abro o Transifex e começo a traduzir, com procedimento similar ao da Carla. Acho que uma vez achei algo em inglês no site e fui lá procurar, mas nem lembro se achei...

#### Quais as maiores, ou mais comuns, pedras no seu caminho?

1. Contexto. As vezes é difícil entender o que está sendo dito, e nem sempre dá pra achar a string no SOen.
2. Glossário. Alguns termos tem que ser padronizados, e apesar de saber disso, não decorei a palavra escolhida. Por exemplo, tive que buscar agora qual termo usamos para *user deletion*. Deletar? Excluir? Apagar? Remover? Achei excluir, mas sei que muitas coisas não estão padronizadas.

#### O que te motiva a traduzir? O que pode ser feito para te motivar mais?

Eu sigo uma *tag* bem parada apenas, então não tem coisa pra fazer lá todo dia, e quando tem, muitos usuários querem responder (isso é ótimo, para a comunidade!).

Quando estou atrás de ajuda, busco em inglês, mas entendo a importância do SOpt, por isso sou motivado a ajudar a comunidade a crescer. De certa forma, vejo como é fácil achar as coisas em inglês, e como nem sempre é fácil em português, o que acaba limitando as pessoas que não falam o nosso idioma.

Reconhecimento seria bacana? Sim, mas não acho que se encaixe no sistema do Stack Exchange em termos de reputação ou medalhas. Se pensarem em algo diferente, legal, mas não acho que deveria ser o principal atrativo.

#### Que ferramentas você sente falta?

Talvez o glossário do próprio Transifex, mas não sei qual útil seria.

Não vejo como o Meta ou o Chat poderiam ser mais úteis, senão como meios de divulgação do Transifex para atrair mais tradutores.

Grandes adições/mudanças ao Transifex sim, seriam úteis. Principalmente porque algumas strings são ridiculamente simples (são as que sempre vão primeiro), e podem ser resolvidas em minutos. Como não fico vigiando com frequência, saber que tem bastante conteúdo seria um bom motivo para passar lá.

#### O que pode ser feito para te ajudar?

Não sei dizer. Não consigo pensar em nada que vá "mudar o jogo". As coisas citadas nas outras respostas seriam interessantes.

#### Algum outro problema?

Talvez a revisão, mas entendo que este é um processo delicado. Seria mais motivador uma revisão mais rápida, mas entendo porque funciona da forma atual.

Comment: Você me fez lembrar de um ponto importante. Na verdade já existe um glossário no Transifex e ele inclusive deixa as palavras sublinhadas caso elas estejam no glossário. O problema é que a palavra tem de ser 'idêntica', então embora 'delete' fique sublinhado, 'deleted' não fica. Um recurso útil seria poder definir esses 'sinônimos' no glossário.

Comment: @carla Eu ia citar isso e esqueci de detalhar. Temos o glossário, mas é pouco preenchido (acho que você que preencheu tudo que tem por lá!), e não funciona TÃO bem quando poderia.