# É permitido debater uma questão sobre programação?

Tags: debate, suporte

Eu posso jogar um debate, uma pergunta que gera opiniões de cada um, no site do **Stack Overflow em Português** (não no Meta), para gerar opiniões, discussões ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Perguntas baseadas em opiniões creio que não seja permitido.

Comment: Não, o modelo do site não permite isso, é uma limitação, baseado em opiniões é um motivo de fechamento de perguntas.

Comment: Por quê no Meta é permitido perguntas baseadas em opiniões e no site principal não?

Comment: No meta as perguntas são relativas a funcionalidades, sugestões e bugs e dúvidas relativas ao site principal, por isso pode-se fazer perguntas e respostas baseadas em opiniões;

Comment: **Acho que seria legal permitir perguntas baseadas em opiniões** (sobre programação) para o Site. Iria atrair mais perguntas, + perguntas = + respostas = + popular = + pessoas

Comment: No meta as discussões e debates são sobre o funcionamento do site, o problema de discussões no site principal é que elas se alogam demais, perdem o foco e a coisa logo vira um flamewar.

Comment: Acho que o modelo adotado pela SE não é adequado, isso funciona melhor em um fórum.

Comment: E existe um fórum da StackOverflow? Não.

Comment: Exemplos: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/514564-qual-e-o-framework-mais-completo-e-qual-e-o-piorzinho/, http://www.guj.com.br/t/duvida-desisitir-da-area-de-t-i/23302 veja se isso parece util? "sempre usei X e me serviu bem, por isso é  o melhor", ninguém sabe onde X foi usado ou o contexto, muito menos se X será bom para outra pessoa.

Comment: Vale lembrar que assuntos/debates fora do escopo do SOpt podem ser discutidos no chat.

Comment: Resposta relacionada: [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/91)

Comment: `Acho que seria legal permitir perguntas baseadas em opiniões (sobre programação) para o Site. Iria atrair mais perguntas, + perguntas = + respostas = + popular = + pessoas.`, nem sempre **quantidade** é sinônimo de **qualidade**...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> @RZ-8121 disse:
>
> *"Existe um fórum da StackOverflow? não"*

Mas é claro que não, a ideia aqui é o Q&A (perguntas e respostas) este é o modelo do site e ponto.

Veja isto que está no [*tour*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas. É construído e administrado por você como parte da rede Stack Exchange de sites de perguntas e respostas. Com a sua ajuda, trabalhamos em conjunto para desenvolver uma biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta sobre programação.

> Somos um pouco diferentes de outros sites.

A SE (stackexchange.com) é uma REDE de sites de Q&A, não apenas de stackoverflows da vida e de programação ou tecnologia da informação, ele é voltado totalmente a "perguntar e responder" com o intuito de criar um bom conteúdo de qualidade.

O **modelo de debate** já foi muito usado por outros sites, a ideia do SO quando foi criada era inovar, ser mais pratico e objetivo, então aqui é assim: tenho uma pergunta e você tem a resposta. Começar misturar as coisas só vai atrapalhar, sistemas de fórum geralmente eram muito cansativos e muita coisa útil neles vai pro "limbo". A ideia era criar algo que "faltava".

Eu participei muito tempo de fóruns (3 fóruns) aonde fui moderador por mais de um ano em um deles, no entanto lá os debates eram prolongados os "bons códigos" e "soluções" se misturavam em meio as conversas e o bom conteúdo se perdia, diariamente surgiam inúmeras duvidas dos quais já tinham respostas, mas ninguém sabia aonde estavam (as vezes sabiam), era muita coisa repetitiva que ofuscava as boas postagens.

Ok, te disse todas as desvantagens do sistema de fórum e o porque Q&A pode ser mais interessante, mas concordo contigo as vezes temos que debater ou queremos trocar uma ideia, por isso a SE trouxe a solução (a um bom tempo), o CHAT.

Veja assim, no campo de comentários quando a conversa começa a ficar muito longa aparece um link pra você exportar a conversação para uma **sala de bate-papo**, lá você pode debater e dar continuidade sem muitas restrições até chegar a solução do problema, depois de resolvido lembre-se de editar a pergunta.

Note também que alguns temas geraram salas aqui mesmo, como por exemplo, uma sala sobre Javascript (vou procurar os links, não lembro como acessar), aonde lá rola umas discussões sobre a linguagens, mas apenas para conversar mesmo.

Quer conversar sobre qualquer coisa, até mesmo que não tenha haver com o site principal (SOpt) então existe uma sala de bate-papo pra isto:

- [Estouro de pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)

---

> @RZ-8121 disse:
>
> Acho que seria legal permitir perguntas baseadas em opiniões (sobre programação) para o Site. Iria atrair mais perguntas, + perguntas = + respostas = + popular = + pessoas

Não é isso que atrai pessoas, eu já participei de vários fóruns, o conteúdo nunca é tão confiável, até mesmo wikis são mais confiáveis devido ao poder de colaborar e melhorar o que já existe.

O *Stack Overflow em inglês* cresceu e se tornou um dos sites mais populares, não com debates, mas com conteúdo mais confiável que os dos fóruns, ou seja o que torna algo popular é o conteúdo confiável (de melhor qualidade) e o próprio SO é um exemplo de que isto funciona e que esta é uma melhor formula para o sucesso ;) (não que seja a melhor e definitiva)

### Resumindo

Aqui no site temos lugar pra tudo, não adianta querer mudar como funciona, existem motivos para o modelo atual funcionar tão bem e existem alternativas como citei para resolver questões de debate de qualquer assunto, até mesmo off-topic, a questão é entender o modelo do site, então se quer mesmo entender (é o minimo que se espera de quem participa) leia e aprenda sobre o modelo:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange

> Nem todos links estão traduzidos, mas o pessoal esta se empenhando nisto (não tive tempo de colaborar e meu inglês é um tanto quanto fraco, mas você pode colaborar em [Como ajudar quem traduz o site?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4764/3635))

Espero que não leve a mal o que falei, só quero que entenda o modelo e porque ele funciona melhor que outros modelos de sites ([be-nice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)).

Answer (score 13):

De vez em quando é muito legal participar de uma discussão envolvendo basicamente opiniões. Pode ser muito instrutivo ver os diferentes pontos de vista e é também revigorante pois acende em nós um desejo de saber mais sobre o assunto.

**Mas o Stack Overflow não é o lugar para isso.**

As razões são simples:

- Discussões tendem a ser longas

  - Isso causa desgaste nos envolvidos, que poderiam estar contribuindo em outros lugares de forma mais construtiva
- Pouca gente se atreve a ler todo o histórico

  - Isso gera comentários repetidos, fora de contexto, inadequados e por aí vai
- Discussões opinativas são pouco relevantes para as pessoas em geral

  - Muita gente não gosta
  - O conteúdo fica defasado rapidamente, pois ninguém vai ficar atualizando cada comentário. Aqui eu lembro muito das discussões sobre mercado de trabalho que já li.
  - Quem tem um problema real a resolver não vai perder tempo lendo uma discussão se tem uma pergunta & resposta. Eu já gastei bastante tempo procurando soluções em páginas e páginas de mensagens em um fórum para perceber que o tópico foi abandonado sem solução.
- Discussões tendem a perder o foco muito facilmente

  - Isso faz com que seja difícil de classificar cada assunto e depois encontrá-lo
  - Também faz com que várias discussões sejam levantadas sobre o mesmo assunto porque as discussões anteriores não chegaram a lugar nenhum.

Enfim, não quero dizer que discussões opinativas como existem em alguns fóruns são necessariamente ruins. Só que não cabem no modelo que temos aqui e provavelmente a maioria dos usuários não iria participar de forma tão intensa. Eu mesmo tenho o tempo limitado e o sistema de perguntas e respostas é mais eficiente para contribuir.

## Faça a pergunta certa

Particularmente, eu acredito que se você tem uma pergunta sobre programação, você **pode** fazê-la aqui, basta fazer da forma correta.

**Sabe quando falam que não existe pergunta idiota? Isso é uma meia verdade. Por trás de cada pergunta tem um dúvida concreta e genuína, mas na maioria das vezes nós simplesmente não sabemos expressá-la.**

Um exemplo claro para mim são perguntas de arquitetura. Alguns chegam e perguntam:

> Qual framework PHP é melhor?

Não tem como responder. Entretanto, em geral há um problema por detrás da pergunta que a pessoa quer resolver, o qual está dentro de um contexto e restrições que tornariam a pergunta viável. Exemplo:

> Precisa desenvolver um Web Service REST em PHP com autenticação OAuth. Existem frameworks PHP com suporte nativo a essas tecnologias?

Na verdade, depois de reformular a pergunta, provavelmente você já conseguirá encontrar a resposta por si mesmo. E, depois de escolher um framework, ainda pode formular perguntas mais específicas, tal como:

> Como configurar autenticação OAuth no Zend Framework?

E assim por diante.

## Outros canais de comunicação

Se, por outro lado, o que você quer é apenas "bater um papo", use o chat ou alguma rede social que será melhor.

Porém, o problema que algumas pessoas tem, é que elas querem tornar essa discussão visível para todos os usuários, afinal discussões em outros canais geralmente atraem outros tipos de pessoa.

Bem, isso não vai acontecer, pois como já disse, as pessoas que estão aqui estão por uma razão, que é justamente evitar todo o "ruído" de comunicação de outros meios.