# Sobre perguntas boas que são fechadas por serem amplas

Tags: debate, perguntas, razões-fechamento, pergunta-subjetiva

Existem **perguntas**  cujo uma resposta realmente não vai solucionar `100%` do problema, mas que existem respostas **precisas** que podem ser valiosas em termos de **orientação**.

Porque marcar como pendente/fechar se existem respostas que vão facilitar o entendimento ou até mesmo clarificar o caminho para a solução da questão ?

Vou citar um exemplo :

[Como tentar deixar um site compatível com os principais browsers? [fechada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112116/como-tentar-deixar-um-site-compat%C3%ADvel-com-os-principais-browsers)

Muitos iniciantes entram no google e digitam algo assim , talvez querendo uma `fórmula mágica` que não existe , mas podem encontrar uma  **orientação** útil em relação ao problema.

Comment: Acho o exemplo dado bem fraco, mas ótima pergunta! [**-1!**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0ebVn.png) :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entendo seu ponto de vista, mas vou tentar lhe explicar aonde este tipo de pergunta vai levar.

Compatibilidade em sites envolvem diversas tecnologias e não uma só, exemplo:

- html4.01, html5
- css2, css3
- javascript (padrão ecma)
- SVG
- Feeds/RSS/ATOM
- Fontes, ttf, woff, etc

Cada navegador evolui mais rápido em uma tecnologia especifica e não tem como definir qual tecnologia ele vai evoluir primeiro, o autor que saber sobre o geral, ele não foi "especifico" em uma tecnologia, quando criamos páginas não usamos uma tecnologia única ou especifica, mas sim uma série de tecnologias como citei, o que torna a pergunta **Ampla demais**.

Entenda por favor, perguntas fechadas não significa que são *ruins* ou *boas*, pelo contrário tem muitas perguntas *boas mesmo*, a questão é que somos um Q&A e temos um modelo a seguir e *"uma cultura local"*, as perguntas e respostas tem que ser especificas, isto é o que faz a comunidade funcionar bem, é esse o segredo do sucesso da maioria dos sites rede *Stack Exchange* (existem sites da SE que são voltados a debates e opiniões e nem todos são sobre programação, existe site sobre Direito, Café e Idiomas).

Os próprios sites da baseados no *Stack Overflow* e o http://stackoverflow.com são a prova de como isso funciona para trazer conteúdo de maior qualidade, se começar a permitir opiniões ou debates vai mudar totalmente o modelo e funcionamento, pode até afetar a qualidade.

Isso já foi debatido aqui no META, veja: [É permitido debater uma questão sobre programação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4872/3635)

Eu sei que a pergunta foi fechada como *Ampla demais*, mas se imaginarmos que ela ficasse aberta, quase todas respostas seriam *opiniões* ou nunca responderiam completamente a duvida, apenas parte. É praticamente impossível responder algo "amplo" quando se tratando de inúmeras tecnologias.

A única resposta que *eu acredito* ser a "correta" seria o que eu comentei lá na pergunta:

- > A única solução é evitar usar tecnologias avançadas usar coisas bem simples se quiser manter compatível com navegadores mais antigos.... Se o caso for todos browsers modernos apenas ie11, edge, Firefox, chrome vai depender da tecnologia estar implementada no navegador ou não. Não existe fórmula mágica e nem pronta pra isto, o jeito é indo testando em quanto constrói em todos navegadores pra evitar dor de cabeça. – [Guilherme Nascimento 7/02 às 19:23](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112116/como-tentar-deixar-um-site-compat%C3%ADvel-com-os-principais-browsers#comment232865_112116)

Ou talvez algo assim (eu pensei em responder isto):

- > A única maneira é usar tecnologias básicas que sejam suportadas por todos browsers, não usar *CSS3*, *HTML5*, *responsividade*, *Web Fonts*, *CORS*, usar *links normais* e evitar o *Ajax* (acaso vá usar CORS), não usar bibliotecas "avançadas" como jQuery e fazer páginas sempre simples.

Qualquer outro tipo de resposta seria apenas *"opinião"* ou *"parte da resposta"* e não teria como afirmar que funcionaria 100%.

Comment: Concordo com boa parte Guilherme ! O que não entendo é porque uma resposta precisa ser o 100% da solução . Até respostas simples que esclarecem uma inviabilidade no meu ponto de vista podem ser construtivas e como o único efeito prático de fechar uma pergunta é impossibilitar novas respostas não vejo muito sentido .

Comment: @JohnDiego acho que não entendeu, deixa me explicar assim, se a pergunta é objetiva mas inviável então ela pode ter uma resposta e pode ser mantida aberta, se a pergunta é ampla pode sim responder com algo *"não é possivel"*, mas devemos fecha-la pelo fato que eu já citei, as resposta que são opinativas, quero dizer, o problema não é a pergunta e sim o tipo de resposta que é prejudicial ao conteúdo de qualidade da comunidade, pois apenas uma resposta será objetiva neste caso ;) - Eu pensei em responder antes de fecharem, mas começou muita discussão lá, então só votei pra fechar.

Comment: Entendi , to mudando meu ponto de vista também , faz sentido !

Comment: @JohnDiego tem um site que não é bem de programação chamado [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) na rede da *Stack Exchange*, lá é saudável ter várias perguntas e geralmente são opiniões pessoais, porque o intuito de lá é *revisar códigos existentes* e para o perfil cultural deles é necessário isto. Cada site tem sua cultura e necessidade, que bom que esta vendo com bons olhos. Se tiver duvidas o META está ae pra isto.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme ! Sou novo no Stack e então é aos poucos que vou entendendo o porque certas coisas acontecem , foi muito esclarecedor a questão de não importar uma pergunta ser boa ou ruim ( claro que ela não deve ser ruim ) mas , não adianta ser boa e não poder ser respondida com certa qualidade devido a amplitude de respostas possíveis .

Comment: @JohnDiego exatamente! E antes que esqueça Seja bem vindo!

Comment: Brigadão mestre !!

Comment: Feito , também n havia me atentado a isso haha ! vlws ( primeira pergunta no meta )

Answer (score 6):

Mesmo fechada, provavelmente essa pergunta permanecerá no site por anos a fio (tem *score* positivo na pergunta e respostas) e o Google vai linkar pra ela, fechada ou não. E sua preocupação sobre "encontrar uma orientação", ainda que incompleta, será satisfeita em boa medida.

As respostas já publicadas com certeza darão *"uma luz"*.
Inclusive esse parece ser um pedido muito frequente (e aqui temos um ótimo meme em busca de ilustração, façam seus GIFs!).

Uma opção legal pra você que já conhece o esquema Stack Overflow é *fazer sua própria pergunta* inspirado por uma pergunta fora de escopo.

Este site não é um blog nem uma página de tutoriais, mas se conseguir calibrar bem a pergunta, com escopo definido e dentro do formato "Pergunta & Resposta", vai matar vários coelhos de uma só vez (com perdão dos veganos):

- a pergunta não vai ser fechada;
- vai servir de referência pra várias outras;
- vai estar sempre aberta a novas respostas;
- se tiver vontade, pode escrever sua própria resposta; (blog!)
- vai ter alcance *muito* maior que qualquer blog ou site de tutoriais;
- o Google vai ficar feliz da vida.

Comment: Perfeito! O ideal agora seria que o AP ou mesmo outra pessoa fizesse uma outra pergunta mais específica, baseado no feedback desta, preferencialmente focando num aspecto específico.

Comment: Excelente ! Cheguei a conclusão de que caso esse tipo de pergunta fosse bem aceito  provavelmente a qualidade do conjunto pergunta / respostas que encontramos no  sopt cairia bastante também pois seria bem comum.

Answer (score 5):

O problema de perguntas como esta, é que elas podem ser tão amplas que podem ter um livro como resposta.

Se eu estive no lugar do AP desta pergunta eu me aprofundaria mais no assunto e dividiria o problema em varias partes fazendo uma pergunta para cada item especifico que envolva compatibilidade entre os Browsers, é claro que isso é uma tarefa custosa de se fazer, mas, mesmo assim a quantidade de reposta e o nível de detalhamento das respostas, seria bem maior do que se fosse em uma pergunta ampla com uma resposta ampla de mais.

Neste casso achei justo o fechamento desta pergunta, mesmo tendo boas respostas, mas, seria melhor fazer varias perguntas especificas.

E como você afirmou:

> Muitos iniciantes entram no google e digitam algo assim , talvez
>   querendo uma fórmula mágica que não existe , mas podem encontrar uma
>   orientação útil em relação ao problema.

Numa resposta muito ampla, acredito que um iniciante iria ficar mais confuso com a quantidade de informação que ele teria que processar para transformar em conhecimento do que em várias perguntas especifica que como um todo pode solucionar um problema ao invés de mostrar o caminho, não que indicar o caminho não seja relevante, mais vamos nos focar na solução aqui no Stack OverFlow Português.

Comment: Se apenas solucionar for o foco do SOpt então sim !