# Posso duplicar uma pergunta na versão em inglês do site?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Eu fico muito feliz do sucesso da versão em português do Stack Overflow, mas eu percebi q não costumo postar na versão em português simplesmente pq eu teria um alcance menor de pessoas.

A minha preocupação é com a segregação da comunidade. Acredito q os sites do SE são para juntar pessoas em volta de um mesmo assunto é isso não acontece quando se tem 2 ou mais sites sobre o mesmo assunto.

Uma melhor abordagem seria dar suporte para múltiplas línguas no mesmo site e é claro q não seriam todas as perguntas e respostas q teriam versões em outras línguas, mas o autor da pergunta ou resposta poderia fornecer uma tradução do texto para alcançar mais pessoas.

Não estou dizendo que não deveriam existir sites com outras línguas que não o inglês, como eu disse eu fico feliz do sucesso do Stack Overflow em Português e da possibilidade de pessoas sem acesso ao inglês ter acesso ao conhecimento contido no Stack Overflow. Só estou dizendo que outros problemas surgem com a solução de criar um site para cada língua e que uma solução de internacionalização (i18n) no mesmo site seria uma solução melhor.

Os problemas e soluções para essa questão são discutidos na questão [As propostas de sites de Stack Overflow (em língua x) são atualmente viáveis?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/are-stack-overflow-in-language-x-proposals-actually-viable/12387#12387). A resposta de JaDogg fez uma boa análise em que expõe os pontos altos e baixos da atual solução:

### O lado bom

- Pessoas sem um bom conhecimento em Inglês ou que simplesmente não preferem Inglês podem participar;
- Não há mais maus entendidos por erros de tradução automática;
- Elimina barreiras de linguagem.

### O lado ruim

- Perguntas duplicadas;
- Dificuldade de representar símbolos de certas linguagens;
- Cria barreiras de conhecimento.

Comment: Visitando o [tour] você ganha 5 pontos de rep também, aproveite e dê uma conferida. :)

Comment: eu ja postei aqui uma pergunta identica a outra de la, só que sem saber, n mexeram em nd da minha pergunta, falando que era duplicada, se vc tiver conta em dois sites com o mesmo e-mail, vc ganha 100 de rep em cada um dos sites que entrar ;)

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo só ganha se você tiver mais de 200 em algum dos outros sites. E realmente duplicatas só são consideradas se forem do mesmo site, se uma pergunta for de outro site da rede, geralmente ela é considerada "fora do escopo"(exceto entre SO's).

Comment: @DiegoF de onde tirou esta informação do primeiro comentário? Isto é novidade?

Comment: Além da duplicata, isto pode ser útil: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/620/101 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/735/101

Comment: Na verdade tem um duplicata que parece melhor, pelo menos para o título (que parece ser diferente do corpo da pergunta, um é pedido de suporte, o outro é debate), quem puder votar nela: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125/101

Comment: @bigown não me recordo bem, mas teve uma ação  minha aqui que não foi por voto recebido que ganhei 5 rep, me parece que foi essa visita ao tour.

Comment: @DiegoF Nunca vi isto acontecer ou ou vi falar. Até onde eu sei só dá pontos, votos recebidos em perguntas e respostas, recompensas recebidas, bônus de cadastro qdo tem reputação em outros sites da rede, bônus por edição aceita e ter feito uma aceitação.

Comment: Os 3 itens do lado ruim não fazem o menor sentido.

Comment: Concordo que o argumento "Dificuldade de representar símbolos de certas linguagens" é fraco, mas não entendo como vc pode achar perguntas duplicadas um mal argumento já que a comunidade SE se preocupa tanto com isso e a barreira de conhecimento é um grande problema já que a resposta pra sua dúvida ainda pode estar em uma língua em que vc não tem acesso (não só em inglês, mas japonês por exemplo).

Comment: Então, não ter um SO em português é uma enorme barreira ao conhecimento. Como ele não tinha um argumento real pra colocar no lado ruim, começou inventar coisas, aí ele colocou um ótimo argumento para ter o site em outra língua como algo contra, não faz o menor sentido. Como pode uma pergunta ser duplicada se ela está em outra língua? Ela só pode ser duplicada se a pessoa puder ler a outra e entender a resposta. Vai no SOjp e tenta ver as respostas pra suas perguntas lá. Além disto Se isto for motivo pra duplicação, todos os sites do mundo podem ter duplicações.Duplicado tem q ser no mesmo site

Answer (score 1):

Uns dos objetivos da Stack Exchange é alcançar um publico maior de pessoas, é necessário que exista comunidades que falem outro idioma que não seja inglês. Por isso existe o Stackoverflow em diferentes línguas:

- [Espanhol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Russo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Japonês](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- [Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Nenhuma nação ou grupo merece ser exilada do conhecimento só porque não fala a língua mais falado do mundo que é o inglês, é importante preservar o conhecimento em outras línguas, é importante oferecer ferramentas tecnológicas em outras línguas, e é desta forma que a Stack Exchange alcança um publico maior. Ainda esta longe de existir apenas uma língua no mundo e eu nem sei se isso seria bom. Se eu fosse desenvolver um produto que pretende-se alcançar um grande publico, eu não desenvolveria apenas em uma língua. Saber inglês hoje é importante porque existe muita informação em inglês, mas, já pensou que pode também existir muita informação interessante em Russo, Mandarim, Japonês ou Espanhol?

O fato de existir o Stackoverflow em Português, é que através desta ferramenta as pessoas dos países que falam português pode ter um grade acervo de soluções, e sem falar que o tempo economizado em se fazer uma pergunta em seu próprio idioma é grande para quem só fala sua própria língua nativa, e isso faz com que a área de Tecnologia da Informação evolua muito mais. Se você quiser [traduzir](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4764/como-ajudar-quem-traduz-o-site) o conteúdo do Stackoverflow em Inglês para o português será ótimo, assim você ajudara as pessoas que só sabem um idioma, e você também pode até traduzir do Português para o inglês ou outros idiomas.